# Explain the "@" symbol in this permissions example

Tags: permissions, files, chmod

I have a file on my Darwin system and the permissions are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@
```

User: read, write, execute
Group: read, execute
Other: read, execute

What is the 11th notation the `@` mean?

In addition to this, I was led to believe that files/directories only had 10 places for their permissions? This, including the missing `d` from the front, would make 11.

Comment: See the duplicate that Stephane references. It has everything you need to know. Also see wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@` means there are "extended attributes".